# R - How do you populate a vector inside a function?

Tags: r, function, loops, vector

I have a complex function. The function works. Inside, there is a vector called `csvcols`, which reads a csv, and creates a list of columns in my csv that have a quality I am looking for.

After my function is complete, `csvcols` is `NULL`, even though when I include `print(csvcols)` within the function, it returns columns, e.g. (1, 3, 5, 6, 7).

How can I get a list of all of the columns after I have looped through my variable, like `for(xx in loop){SumofGeneration}`?

```
SumofGeneration <- function(xx) {
csvcols = c()
    for(i in 1:length(xx)) {
            func2(xx[i])
        if( func2(xx[i]) == T){
            csvcols <- c(csvcols, which(colnames(filename) %in% xx[i]))
                             }
}
xxgeneration <- rowSums(filename[,csvcols])
}

#Generates list of relevant cols (csvcols vector) in file (filename)
#Sums values in those cols and returns xxgeneration


loop <- c( 14 strings here)
For (xx in loop){
SumofGeneration(xx)}
```

I have tried saving my csvcols as:

```
csvcols2 <- c(csvcols2, csvcols)
```

My loop runs `SumofGeneration` on 14 strings in my list (loop), and within the function generates values in `csvcols`, and then when the function ends I lose these values and `csvcols = NULL`.

`csvcols2` always returns NULL. How can I stop losing my values?
I want my output to be a vector with all 14 `csvcols` values in one vector - `csvcols2`.

Comment: Read about variable scoping in R. Variables inside a function are LOCAL to that function unless you tell R to make them GLOBAL. So when the function runs it creates `csvcols`, populates it, then promptly deletes it once the function finishes. Solve this by "returning" the `csvcols` variable at the end of the function with `return(csvcols)` or by assigning `csvcols` to the GLOBAL environment using the `assign()` function.

Comment: After following your suggested reading, the <<-  operator seems to perform the desired function.
Thanks for the help!